# PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME = ? and JOB_KEY =?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I want the **Spring Batch metadata** to be created on the MySQL server and used all the existing tables from Oracle to fetch data from it and put it into the MongoDB.

I created the following configurations, but somehow missing the trick to create the Spring Batch metadata tables though configuration.

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=MY_DB

#By default, Spring runs all the job as soon as it has started its context.
spring.batch.job.enabled=false

spring.batch.initialize-schema=always
spring.batch.tablePrefix=test.BATCH_
#spring.batch.initializer.enabled=false
spring.batch.schema=org/springframework/batch/core/schema-mysql.sql

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1527:OR_DEV
spring.datasource.username=EDR_USR
spring.datasource.password=txz$2Zhr
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

jdbc.batch.jdbcUrl=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useSSL=false
jdbc.batch.username=root
jdbc.batch.password=root
jdbc.batch.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

DBConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class DBConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean(name="oracleDS")
    public DataSource batchDataSource(){          
           return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                    .url(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"))
                    .driverClassName(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.driver-class-name"))
                    .username(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"))
                    .password(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"))
                    .build();          
    } 

    @Bean(name="mysqlDS")
    @Primary
    public DataSource mysqlBatchDataSource(){          
           return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                    .url(env.getProperty("jdbc.batch.jdbcUrl"))
                    .driverClassName(env.getProperty("jdbc.batch.driver-class-name"))
                    .username(env.getProperty("jdbc.batch.username"))
                    .password(env.getProperty("jdbc.batch.password"))
                    .build();          
    }
}
```

Job

```
@GetMapping("/save-student")
    public String saveStudent() {
        JobParameters params = new JobParametersBuilder()
                .addString("JobID", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .addString("Job_ID", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .addDate("date", new Date())
                .toJobParameters();
        try {
            JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(countryJob, params);
            log.debug("Job Status : " + jobExecution.getStatus());
        } catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException | JobRestartException | JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException
                | JobParametersInvalidException e) {
            log.error("Job Failed : "+e.getMessage());
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Error:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-03-27T14:57:52.745+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME = ? and JOB_KEY = ?]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'test.batch_job_instance' doesn't exist",
    "path": "/save-student"
}
```

Comment: Please share your spring batch configuration as well. Do you use a custom batch configurer? I see you are manually creating data sources, do you use Spring Boot?

Comment: Yes I am using Spring Boot... but I am not using  custom batch configurer. Could you please guide ?

Comment: I can't see from what you shared what's wrong. The datasource you annotated with `@Primary` should be the one used for Spring Batch and initialized by Spring Boot (according to `spring.batch.initialize-schema=always`) with batch meta-data.

Comment: Since we've two dataSources, Spring Batch is unable to create the metadata tables automatically and hence this error is coming. I executed the script manually as a workaround, but is there any way to fixed this issue through code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fixed this issue, I executed the MYSQL spring batch metadata tables manually by executing the script from here: [MySQL Spring Batch Metadata tables script](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-core/src/main/resources/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-mysql.sql)

Since we've two dataSources, Spring Batch is unable to create the metadata tables automatically and hence this error is coming. I executed the script manually as a workaround, but is there any way to fixed this issue through code?

Answer (score 5):

Write below code in application.properites file. It will automatically generate tables required for the spring batch.

```
spring.batch.initialize-schema=always
```

Comment: Its now `spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema=always`

Answer (score 3):

```
spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema=always
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error when I migrated to Spring boot 3 and jdk 17.

Apart from adding spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema=always in application file.

You should remove @EnableBatchProcessing from your spring batch config. As it is no longer required in spring batch 5.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/4336

Comment: After upgrading to java 21 and Spring Boot 3.2.1, this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

After spend some time, I could achieve the results i hoped by setting the batch datasource as @Primary. Like this:

Datasource configuration

```
@Bean
@Primary
public DataSource batchDataSource() {
    return batchDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.batch")
public DataSourceProperties batchDataSourceProperties() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
}
```

OR, In the Batch configuration i set  the data source

```
@Component
public class BatchDSConfiguration extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {
@Override
@Autowired(required = false)
public void setDataSource(@Qualifier("batchDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
    super.setDataSource(dataSource);        
}
...
```

}

Application properties

```
spring.datasource.batch.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.batch.url=jdbc:h2:mem:batchdb
spring.datasource.batch.username=sb
spring.datasource.batch.password=
spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema=ALWAYS
```

I Tried to create a custom JobRepository in the BatchConfigurer, but could not create the batch schema with multiple data sources. I Will try more and if i can do it i'll come back here to tell.

Hope it helps.